# How do you get a div within the thumbnail element in twitter bootstrap to re-size correctly?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and I wanted to do a crossfade animation on my thumbnail images, so I created two separate classes with different z indexes that I then put in the thumbnail tag. I then used some simple jquery to get the top layer to fade out on mouseenter and fade in on mouseleave. It all looks great, but now I'm having difficulties with the fact that when I resize the window the images don't flow nicely.

The thumbnails start to overlap and re-size awkwardly. Here is a sample of the code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span3">
  <div class="thumbnail top">
    <img class="hover_image" src="assets/img/hoversquare.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail bottom">
    <img src="assets/img/hoversquare1.png"/>
  </div>
  </li>

... (there are four of these <li> elements
```

The classes I used were:

```
.bottom {
    position: absolute;

    z-index:1;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
 }
```

Also, included hte twitter bootstrap css file which is: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: Can you include any relevant code in the classes you use?  Not enough here to go on.

Comment: .bottom {
 position: absolute;

 z-index:1;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
 }

Also, the bootstrap.css file which has a bunch more to define thumbnail and thumbnails, can be found: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue in IE9 and found that the `position: absolute` was causing an issue for me.  Not exactly as you described but I was able to eliminate the issue with using `position: relative` in the `.top` and `.bottom` classes.  This [link](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex) may also be useful.

Comment: As soon as I change to position relative the img's don't overlap anymore, which is what caused the fade transition to work in the first place. I did play around with that before and found that position:relative fixed the reflow issue but then broke the fade transition - hence looking for a way to keep img's overlapping but also reflowing properly.

Comment: hi @JaclynKonzelmann can you include the code structure also? or a link would be pretty useful too!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all the re-sizing is done via the media queries... I would try to adjust the css to fit your needs... create your-responsive.css and define your styling per all media sizes that you want to address in that file... it will override the bootstraps responsive css and thus you can implement whatever changes you need...